# Is there a way in Colab to generate animation dynamically?

Tags: python, animation, google-colaboratory

I wrote a Langton's ant code and I wanted to have the animation run in Colab until it is stopped by user or after a certain number of frames. As it is right now, it first generates all the frames, then compiles them into animation and then displays it. If there are a lot of frames, it takes forever and/or Colab runs out of memory. That's why I was hoping there was a way to just generate it one frame at a time and continuously update the image.
It doesn't seem like FuncAnimation has that capability, but maybe I'm just not seeing it.
If anyone knows of a way or documentation that would be helpful, please let me know.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation, rc, colors
from IPython.display import HTML

N = 40
ant = np.array([N//2, N//2])
move = {'N': [0, 1], 'E': [1, 0], 'S': [0, -1], 'W': [-1, 0]}
d = ['N', 'E', 'S', 'W']
facing = 1
board = np.zeros((N, N))
color = 0
board[ant[0]][ant[1]] = 4

cmap = colors.ListedColormap(['darkgreen', 'limegreen', 'greenyellow', 'yellow', 'red'])


def turn(direction):
    if direction == 'R':
        return (facing + 1) % 4
    else:
        return (facing - 1) % 4


def update(data):
    global ant, board, facing, color
    if color in [0, 1]:
        facing = turn('R')
    else:
        facing = turn('L')

    board[ant[0]][ant[1]] = (color + 1) % 4
    ant += move[str(d[facing])]
    color = board[ant[0]][ant[1]]
    board[ant[0]][ant[1]] = 4

    mat.set_data(board)
    return [mat]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 5));

ax.grid(False)
plt.axis('off')

mat = ax.matshow(board, cmap=cmap)
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames = 150, interval = 1, repeat=False, blit=True)

rc('animation', html='jshtml')
ani
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems your code is missing an update. By your description you're making a ton of plots without clearing them. Check out this weird gif thing of some flags

```
from IPython.display import SVG, display
out=display(SVG(url='http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/a4/Flag_of_the_United_States.svg'), display_id=True)
while True:
    out.update(SVG(url='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fa/Flag_of_the_People%27s_Republic_of_China.svg'))
    out.update(SVG(url='http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/a4/Flag_of_the_United_States.svg'))
```

the key part here is out.update. You have an update function.

space

It also looks like Widgets exist in Goolge Colab, and they have a notebook to show for it: https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/widgets.ipynb

And it looks like you can animate stuff using Bokeh, I don't know if it's possible, but I'm 100 percent sure that it's possible.
https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/charts.ipynb#scrollTo=nv8P3UYm6SiQ

Answer (score 0):

You can add frames in your FuncAnimation argument and use the following command.
Although there is a limit, but this will increase some frames in your animation. This is simply to raise the animation limit to a large value.

```
matplotlib.rcParams['animation.embed_limit'] = 2**128
```

Answer (score -2):

AHHH this took me four hours, but was totally worth it!

```
out = display(Image.fromarray((cmap(board)*255.0).astype('uint8'),'RGBA'), display_id=True)
for i in range(200):
    #print(cmap(board))
    time.sleep(0.1)
    update(board)
    image=Image.fromarray(cmap(board),'RGBA')
    out.update(Image.fromarray((cmap(board)*255).astype('uint8'),'RGBA'))
```

Comment: I'm still pretty pissed off you downvoted my first comment.,
anyway your answer is right here: https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/widgets.ipynb